# Add a row to the top of a Table (LibGdx)

Tags: java, libgdx

How can I add a line at the top of a Table in LibGdx ?

```
tableName.add(rowElement);
```

In this way, it adds a line to the end of the table (bottom). I need to do the opposite.

```
tableName.add(rowElement).align(Align.top); // didn't work
```

Code:

```
Table mainTable = new Table();
mainTable.center().top();

Table message = new Table(skin);
Label messageName = new Label("ImYourFather", skin);
message.add(messageName).row();

Label messageText= new Label("THIRD MeSSaGE", skin);
message.add(messageText).row();

mainTable.add(message).align(Align.top).row();
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code so we can simulate fast? it seems like you have to use .jquery's .prepend or .before

Comment: @Einlanzer This is a Java/LibGDX question.

Comment: @Erick, please post a more complete code example that shows what you are doing. The Alignment is meant only for the content of the cell. It's not related to the cell within the Table.

Comment: @noone Posted code sample

Comment: Your code and the picture don't really match. Usually you get something at the top of the table by just inserting it first (first row).

Comment: When i used mainTable.add(message) - the added line is the last and not the first row.

Comment: you seem to add the table "message" to another table "mainTable" can you maybe show the code of this table, too?

Comment: @donfuxx , dont know how can this solve this question. changed "Code"

Comment: But where do you add the label with text "NEED PaSTe TO TOP" in your code? Where the "Hello" label? Your code doesn't match the posted image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer : you can't insert in a libgdx Table (directly)**

However, there are workarounds.

According to libgdx [documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table#inserting-cells) :

> Table allows a cell's widget to be changed or removed (by setting it
>   to null), but Table currently does not allow cells to be inserted in
>   the middle or removed. To do that, the Table needs to be rebuilt: call
>   clearChildren to remove all children and cells, then add them all to
>   the Table again.
>
> If inserting or removing cells is needed, VerticalGroup or HorizontalGroup can be used.

So you can't insert cells at the top of your Table. You need to rebuild the table entirely from the beginning, or alternatively to use the [VerticalGroup](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/VerticalGroup.html) class as recommended.

---

**First solution :** Rebuild the table each time you want to insert a message at the top.

---

**Second Solution :** Use Vertical Group

```
 // Initialize
 VerticalGroup v = new VerticalGroup();
 v.addActor(new Label("First row", skin))
 v.addActor(new Label("Second Row", skin))
 v.pack();
 myScene.addActor(v);

 ...

 // Add to the 'top'
 v.addActorAt(0, new Label("I'm at the first row", skin));
 v.pack();
```

*I haven't tested this code, but it should help you get the gist of it*

However by doing so, be aware that you will lose a part of libgdx Table's power.